# w.a.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter : An internal error occurred while trying to authenticate the user

Tags: java, mysql, twitter-bootstrap, spring-boot

I'm cannot do login in my system. When I insert data in my web form and click in Login button my system don't work.(The datas is correct).

**User entity:**

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "usr_usuarios")
    public class Usuario {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        @Column(name = "usr_id")
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "usr_email", nullable = false, length = 100)
        @NotNull(message = "O email é obrigatório")
        @Length(min = 5, max = 100, message = "O email deve conter entre 5 e 100 caracteres.")
        private String email;

        @Column(name = "usr_senha", nullable = false, length = 100)
        @NotNull(message = "A senha é obrigatório")
        private String senha;

        public Long getId() {
            return id;
        }

        public void setId(Long id) {
            this.id = id;
        }

        public String getEmail() {
            return email;
        }

        public void setEmail(String email) {
            this.email = email;
        }

        public String getSenha() {
            return senha;
        }

        public void setSenha(String senha) {
            this.senha = senha;
        }
}
```

**User repository:**

```
public interface RepositorioUsuario extends JpaRepository<Usuario, Long> {

    Usuario findByEmail(String email);
}
```

**Security Config:**

```
@Configuration
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter{

    @Autowired
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Autowired
    private DataSource dataSource;

    @Value("${spring.queries.users-query}")
    private String userQuery;

    @Value("${spring.queries.roles-query")
    private String roleQuery;

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception{
        auth
        .jdbcAuthentication().usersByUsernameQuery(userQuery)
        .authoritiesByUsernameQuery(roleQuery)
        .dataSource(dataSource)
        .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception{
        http
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/login").permitAll()
            .antMatchers("/registration").permitAll()
            .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                    .and().csrf().disable()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/login?error=true").defaultSuccessUrl("/")
                    .usernameParameter("email").passwordParameter("senha")
                .and().logout()
                    .logoutRequestMatcher(new AntPathRequestMatcher("/logout")).logoutSuccessUrl("/login");
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/webjars/**");
    }
```

**application.properties:**

```
# Thymeleaf
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false

# Spring Data
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tw_gerenciador_tarefas?useTimezone=true&serverTimezone=UTC
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update

# TomCat
server.port = 8090

# SpringSecurity
spring.queries.users-query=SELECT usr_email AS username, usr_senha AS password, 1 AS active FROM usr_usuarios WHERE usr_email=?
spring.queries.roles-query=SELECT usr_email AS username, 'ROLE_USER' AS role FROM usr_usuarios WHERE usr_email=?
```

**accountController:**

```
public class ContaController {

    @Autowired
    private ServicoUsuario servicoUsuario;

    @GetMapping("/login")
    public String login() {
        return "conta/login";
    }
}
```

**Login page:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/webjars/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Gerenciador de tarefas</a>
    </nav>

    <div class="container">
        <h3>Login</h3>
        <form action="/login" method="post" class="form-signin">
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="E-mail" name="email">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Senha" name="senha">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Login</button>
            </div>
            <div class=form-group>
                <div class="col-md-9">
                    <div class="alert alert-danger" role="alert" th:if="${param.error}">
                        Não foi possivel fazer login
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class=form-group>
                <span>Não possui conta? <a href="/registration">Registra-se</a></span>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <script src="/webjars/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/webjars/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**Error message:**

> org.springframework.security.authentication.InternalAuthenticationServiceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [${spring.queries.roles-query]; Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
>       at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:123) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.authenticate(AbstractUserDetailsAuthenticationProvider.java:144) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:175) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.authentication.ProviderManager.authenticate(ProviderManager.java:200) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.attemptAuthentication(UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter.java:94) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.doFilter(AbstractAuthenticationProcessingFilter.java:212) ~[spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:116) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:74) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:105) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:56) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:334) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:215) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:178) [spring-security-web-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:357) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:270) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:99) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:92) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.HiddenHttpMethodFilter.doFilterInternal(HiddenHttpMethodFilter.java:93) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:200) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:109) [spring-web-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:193) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:166) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:202) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:96) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:490) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:139) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:74) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:343) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:408) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:66) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:853) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1587) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [na:1.8.0_211]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [na:1.8.0_211]
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.21.jar:9.0.21]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_211]
>   Caused by: org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: PreparedStatementCallback; SQL [${spring.queries.roles-query]; Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.doTranslate(SQLStateSQLExceptionTranslator.java:110) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:72) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.support.AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.translate(AbstractFallbackSQLExceptionTranslator.java:81) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.translateException(JdbcTemplate.java:1442) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:632) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:668) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:699) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:711) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:762) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadUserAuthorities(JdbcDaoImpl.java:248) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.jdbc.JdbcDaoImpl.loadUserByUsername(JdbcDaoImpl.java:199) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider.retrieveUser(DaoAuthenticationProvider.java:108) ~[spring-security-core-5.1.5.RELEASE.jar:5.1.5.RELEASE]
>       ... 54 common frames omitted
>   Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (1 > number of parameters, which is 0).
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:129) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:97) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:89) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:63) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.checkBounds(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1370) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.getCoreParameterIndex(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1383) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
>       at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ClientPreparedStatement.setString(ClientPreparedStatement.java:1750) ~[mysql-connector-java-8.0.16.jar:8.0.16]
>       at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setString(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-3.2.0.jar:na]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:400) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValueInternal(StatementCreatorUtils.java:232) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.StatementCreatorUtils.setParameterValue(StatementCreatorUtils.java:163) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.doSetValue(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:69) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.setValues(ArgumentPreparedStatementSetter.java:50) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:675) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:616) ~[spring-jdbc-5.1.8.RELEASE.jar:5.1.8.RELEASE]
>       ... 61 common frames omitted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here. You miss `}` at the end of `spring.queries.roles-query` :

```
@Value("${spring.queries.roles-query")
private String roleQuery;
```

It should be :

```
@Value("${spring.queries.roles-query}")
private String roleQuery;
```